# PHP/PDO Using an associative array to navigate through record sets.

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, associative-array

I have a simple program that I am trying to implement some sort of pagination/capability to navigate through individual records in a MySQL database. The code itself calls a function that returns an associative array so that the records may be navigated sequentially in the case of non-sequential indices being made by deletes.

```
function getKeys($handle, $user, $password) {

    try {

         $conn = new PDO($handle,$user,$password);
         $conn -> setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

        }

    catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo "Error connectiong to database. Error: (" . $e -> getMessage() . ")";

    }

    $sql = "Select Workstation_ID from Workstation"; 

    $result = $conn -> query($sql);
    $resultArray = array();

    while ( $row = $result -> fetch()) {

        $resultArray[] = $row;
    }

    $conn = null;

    return $resultArray; }
```

I am attempting to store the result from this function into a variable and from there try to increment that variable for use in an other function:

```
    $Keys = getKeys($dsn,$un,$pw);

    $i = 0;

    $currID = $Keys[$i][0];

    $row = getResultSet($dsn,$un,$pw,$currID);
```

I would then use the $row to display the current workstation :

```
    echo "<hr class='viewHR'>";
    echo "</br></br><div class='viewFormat'>";
    echo "<form name = 'updateWorkstationForm' action ='updateWorkstation.php' method  ='post'>";
    echo "<b>Workstation Name:</b><br><input type = 'Textbox' name = 'pcName' value = '" . $row['Workstation_Name'] . "'/></br>";
    echo "<b>Serial Number: </b><br> <input type = 'Textbox' name = 'SN' value = '" . $row['Serial_Number'] . "'/></br>";

    echo "<b>Model</b></br>";

    echo "<select name ='modelSelect'>";
    echo "<option value = '".$row['Model_ID'] . "'>" .  $row['Model'] . "</option>";
    echo "</select></br>";

    echo "<b>Department</b></br>";
    echo "<select name ='DepartmentSelect'>";
    echo "<option value = '".$row['Department_ID'] . "'>" .  $row['Department'] . "   </option>";
    echo "</select></br>";
```

I was wondering if I was going about this completely wrong or how I would approach incrementing the array's index to display each record on a click of an anchor tag or button the whole file is as follows :

```
<html>
<body>
    <div>
        <?php

            $un = "xxx";
            $pw = "xxxxxx";
            $dsn = "mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=xxxxxxxxxxx";

            $Keys = getKeys($dsn,$un,$pw);

            $i = 0;

            $currID = $Keys[$i][0];

            $row = getResultSet($dsn,$un,$pw,$currID); 

            echo "<hr class='viewHR'>";
            echo "</br></br><div class='viewFormat'>";
            echo "<form name = 'updateWorkstationForm' action ='updateWorkstation.php' method = 'post'>";
            echo "<b>Workstation Name:</b><br> <input type = 'Textbox' name = 'pcName' value = '" . $row['Workstation_Name'] . "'/></br>";
            echo "<b>Serial Number: </b><br> <input type = 'Textbox' name = 'SN' value = '" . $row['Serial_Number'] . "'/></br>";

            echo "<b>Model</b></br>";
            echo "<select name ='modelSelect'>";
            echo "<option value = '".$row['Model_ID'] . "'>" .  $row['Model'] . "</option>";
            echo "</select></br>";

            echo "<b>Department</b></br>";
            echo "<select name ='DepartmentSelect'>";
            echo "<option value = '".$row['Department_ID'] . "'>" .  $row['Department'] . "</option>";
            echo "</select></br>";

            echo "<b>Room</b></br>";
            echo "<select name ='RoomSelect'>";
            echo "<option value = '".$row['Room_ID'] . "'>" .  $row['Room'] . "</option>";
            echo "</select></br>";

            echo "<b>Property Status</b> </br>";
            echo "<select name = 'propertyStatus'>";
            echo "<option value = '".$row['Property_Status_ID'] . "'>" .  $row['Property_Status'] . "</option>";
            echo "</select></br>";

            if ($row['Property_Status'] != "Owned"){
                echo "<b>Lease Company:</b> ";
                echo "<select name = leaseSelect>";
                echo "<option value = '" . $row['Lease_Info_ID'] ."'>Company:" . $row['Company'] . ", Start: " . $row['Start_Date'] . "End: " .$row['End_Date'] . "</option>";
                echo "</select></br>";
            }

            echo "<b>Cart</b></br>";
            echo "<select name ='cartSelect'>";
            echo "<option value = '".$row['Cart_ID'] . "'>" .  $row['Cart_Type'] . "</option>";
            echo "</select></br>";

            echo "<b>Workstation Comments: </b><br> <Textarea rows='5' cols='60' name = 'wsComments'> ". $row['Workstation_Comment'] . " </Textarea></br>";

            echo "<b>Location Comments: </b><br> <Textarea rows='5' cols='60' name = 'locComments'> ". $row['Workstation_Comment'] . " </Textarea></br>";
            echo "<input type = 'submit' value = 'Update' />";
            echo "<input type = 'button' value = 'Cancel' onclick = 'location.reload(this);' />";
            echo "</form>";
            echo "</div>"; 

            /*Function to return a parallel array. This is so that non-sequential records in the database may be described sequentially with the help of an array's indices*/
            function getKeys($handle, $user, $password) {

                try {

                    $conn = new PDO($handle,$user,$password);
                    $conn -> setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
                }

                catch(PDOException $e) {

                    echo "Error connectiong to database. Error: (" . $e -> getMessage() . ")";
                }

                $sql = "Select Workstation_ID from Workstation"; 

                $result = $conn -> query($sql);
                $resultArray = array();

                while ( $row = $result -> fetch()) {

                    $resultArray[] = $row;
                }

                $conn = null;

                return $resultArray; 
            }


            function getResultSet($handle, $user, $password, $ID) {

                $resultSet = "";

                try {

                    $conn = new PDO($handle,$user,$password);
                    $conn -> setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
                }

                catch(PDOException $e) {

                    echo "Error connectiong to database. Error: (" . $e -> getMessage() . ")";
                }

                $sql = "Select Workstation.Workstation_ID,Workstation.Model_ID,Workstation.Property_Status_ID,workstation.Lease_Info_ID, Workstation.Workstation_Name, Workstation.Serial_Number, Model.Model, Department.Department,Room.Room,Property_Status.Property_Status,Lease_Info.Start_Date,Lease_Info.End_Date,Lease_Info.Company,Lease_Info.Lease_Comment,Cart.Cart_Type,Workstation.Workstation_Comment,Workstation.Location_Comment from Workstation INNER JOIN Model ON Workstation.Model_ID = Model.Model_ID  INNER JOIN Department ON Workstation.Department_ID = Department.Department_ID INNER JOIN Room ON Workstation.Room_ID = Room.Room_ID INNER JOIN Property_Status ON Workstation.Property_Status_ID = Property_Status.Property_Status_ID INNER JOIN Lease_Info ON Workstation.Lease_Info_ID = Lease_Info.Lease_Info_ID INNER JOIN Cart ON Workstation.Cart_ID = Cart.Cart_ID where Workstation_ID = :ID"; 

                $pstmt = $conn -> prepare($sql);

                if(!$pstmt) {
                    echo "Error preparing the statement. Error: (" . $conn -> ErrorInfo() . ")";
                }

                $pstmt -> bindParam(':ID', $ID);

                try {

                    $pstmt -> execute();
                }

                catch(PDOException $e) {

                    echo "Failed to execute prepared Statement. Error:  (" . $e -> getmessage() . ")";
                }

                $resultSet = $pstmt -> fetch();

                return $resultSet;

                $conn = null;
            }
        ?>  

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Any criticism, insight, or pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you're going to store the entire resultset in an array, better to use `fetchAll()` method.

Comment: "I am attempting to store the result from this function into a variable and from there try to increment that variable for use in an other function" - I read your code but I still don't know how to increment an array of nominal data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn’t be fetching *all* records if you only intend to display a subset, or just one.

To paginate, use the `LIMIT` clause. So, if you split records into pages of ten, then to get the first page your query would be:

```
SELECT * FROM workstations LIMIT 0,10
```

Where the first number is the offset, and the second number is the number of records after the offset you wish to fetch. To fetch the second page, you’d change the limit clause to be `LIMIT 10,10`; to fetch the third page `LIMIT 20,10`, and so on. The PHP equation is:

```
$offset = (($page - 1) * $records_per_page);
```

The page value can come from a `$_GET` variable, like http://www.example.com/?page=1.

Secondly, if you’re only wanting to display one record, then fetch that one:

```
SELECT * FROM workstations WHERE id = ? LIMIT 1
```

Pass the ID via a `$_GET` parameter again, and use PDO to bind it to avoid SQL injection vulnerabilities:

```
<?php

$sql = "SELECT * FROM workstations WHERE id = :id LIMIT 1";

$sth = $db->prepare($sql);
$sth->bindParam(':id', $_GET['id'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sth->execute();
$row = $sth->fetchObject();
```

Comment: This is working but I cannot seem to figure out how I would increment the id. I am intending on being able to hit a next button and viewing the next record in the database I cannot just increment it by one because the ID's aren't sequential seeing as each workstation may be deleted.

Comment: @Taylz You’d probably want to issue another query in that case: `SELECT id FROM workstations WHERE id > :current_id ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT ` will fetch the next record’s ID (if there is one).

Comment: Thank you so much I was going about it the wrong way for longer than I'd care to admit and that makes a lot of sense. Thanks again and have a great day.